# Default value for a bool within a struct in C when accessed by dereferencing a pointer allocated memory using calloc

Tags: c, pointers

Consider the code below -

```
typedef struct meh {
    int a;
    bool valid;
} var;

int main(){
    var *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(var));
    return 1;
}
```

I know that calloc by default initializes memory to 0 (or equivalent). Would that still be the case for valid. Is it safe to say that:

```
ptr->valid;
```

would always return False (unless explicitly initialised to true) for dereferencing a pointer(like ptr) which was allocated memory using calloc.

Comment: The type `bool` (which really is an alias for `_Bool`) is basically an integer variable that can hold the values `0` and `1`. So if you set the memory of a `bool` variable to `0` then it would be `false` (which is really a macro defined as the integer `0`, for now).

Comment: What exactly is the question here? My guess is _Does a struct field of type `bool` contain value `false`, when allocating struct with `calloc` and accessing the field through the pointer from that?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`calloc()` gives you a zero-initialized buffer. So, in `ptr->valid` will be zero, hence `false`.

```
#define bool    _Bool
#if defined __STDC_VERSION__ && __STDC_VERSION__ > 201710L
#define true    ((_Bool)+1u)
#define false   ((_Bool)+0u)
#else
#define true    1
#define false   0
#endif
```

The above snippet is from `stdbool.h` header file, in which it is clearly defined that `false` is `0`.

And, will you stop using `return 1;`, it says *error occurred* instead use `return 0;` or `return EXIT_SUCCESS;`.

Try running the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct meh {
    int a;
    bool valid;
} var;

int main(void)
{
    var *ptr = calloc(1, sizeof(var));
    if(ptr->valid)
        puts("true\n");
    else 
        puts("false\n");

    printf("%d\n", false); // prints 0
    free(ptr);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(“C 2018” means [the 2018 C standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/81656/298225).)

C 2018 6.2.5 6 says “… The type `_Bool` and the unsigned integer types that correspond to the standard signed integer types are the *standard unsigned integer types*.”

C 2018 6.2.6.2 5 says “… For any integer type, the object representation where all the bits are zero shall be a representation of the value zero in that type.”

Therefore, any `_Bool` in space allocated with `calloc` will have the value zero until changed, and zero serves as false in various places in C.

(For completeness, C 2018 7.22.3.2 2 says memory allocated with `calloc` is initialized to all bits zero, and C 2018 6.2.5 17 says “The type `char`, the signed and unsigned integer types, and the enumerated types are collectively called integer types…”)